# PHP echo not displaying in DIV

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a HTML page that loads a PHP file into a DIV like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Intranet</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="javascript:void()" onclick=$('#content').load('test.php'); return false">Employee Lookup</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>
 <div class="content-center" id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The DIV is named content.

The PHP file has a search form in a DIV and the PHP script does a database search and echos the retrieved data into a DIV on the same page. This works fine if I don't load the PHP file into a DIV on the main HTML page. When I load the PHP file in the DIV, the form in the PHP file displays correctly in the DIV on the main page, however the search results don't. They don't display at all and the DIV just displays the original HTML page. Not sure why this is happening.

Here's the code for the PHP file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/HelperFunctions.js"></script>
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/open-sans-condensed:n3:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1 class="page-title">Employee Directory Lookup:</h1>
<form name="phonesearch" action="" method="GET" style="text-align: center">
Name <input type="text" id="user" name="user"> &nbsp;
Unit <input type="text" id="unit"> $nbsp;
Roles <input type="text" name="role"> &nbsp;
Number <input type="text" name="number" > &nbsp;
<input name="search" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    document.forms['phonesearch'].elements['user'].focus();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#D7D2C2");
  $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#E6E6E6");
});
</script>
<div class="result">
<?php
 if(!empty(isset($_GET['search']))) {
    clearstatcache();
    $searchName = htmlspecialchars($_GET["user"]);
    $searchUnit = htmlspecialchars($_GET["unit"]);
    $searchRole = htmlspecialchars($_GET["role"]);
    $searchNum = htmlspecialchars($_GET["number"]);
    $username = "test";
    $password = "test";
    try {
        // Initiate database connection using PDO prepared statements.
        $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=ServerName\DatabaseName;Database=001active",$username,$password);

        // Add wildcards to our search strings so that they are more searchable.
        $searchName = explode(' ',$searchName);
            $searchName1 = '%' . $searchName[0] . '%';
        if (count($searchName) > 1)
            $searchName2 = '%' . $searchName[1] . '%';
        else
            $searchName2 = '%%';
        $searchRole = '%' . $searchRole . '%';
        $searchNum = FormatNumber($searchNum);
        // The actual query we'll run. Don't worry about it...
        $sql = "SELECT PMMain.NAME_FULLB, PMMain.NAME_OTHER, PMMain.WORK_PHONE, PMMain.OTHER_PHONE,
            PMMain.CELLULAR, PMMain.STATUS_COMMENT, PMUser.USR_FIELD_11,
            PMUser.USR_FIELD_12, PMMain.NAME_FIRST, PMMain.NAME_LAST,
            PMMain.NAME_OTHER, PMMain.OTHER_CONTACT, PMUser.USR_MEMO_2, PMUser.USR_MEMO_1
            FROM PMUser INNER JOIN PMMain ON PMUser.ID = PMMain.ID
            WHERE PMMain.NAME_FULLB NOT LIKE ',%' AND PMMain.COMPANY_CODE = 'ACTIVE' AND
            (PMMain.NAME_FULLB LIKE :search_user OR PMMain.NAME_OTHER LIKE :search_user2
            OR PMMain.NAME_FULL LIKE :search_user3) AND
            (PMMain.NAME_FULLB LIKE :search2_user OR PMMain.NAME_OTHER LIKE :search2_user2
            OR PMMain.NAME_FULL LIKE :search2_user3) AND
            (PMUser.USR_MEMO_2 LIKE :search_role OR PMUser.USR_MEMO_2 IS NULL) AND PMUser.USR_FIELD_11 LIKE :search_Unit
            ORDER BY PMMain.NAME_LAST ASC";
            // Prepare the query!
            $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
            // Assign the variables in the SQL query to our 'get' variables.
        $statement->bindParam(':search_user', $searchName1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':search_user2', $searchName1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':search_user3', $searchName1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':search2_user', $searchName2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':search2_user2', $searchName2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':search2_user3', $searchName2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':search_role', $searchRole, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':search_Unit', $searchUnit, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        // Run the query!
        $statement->execute();
        // Return the data
        if ($data = $statement->fetchAll()){
            // Table headers
            echo '<table align="center" padding-right="15px"><tr><tr><th>Unit</th><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Other Name</th>
            <th>Roles</th><th>Work Phone</th><th>Direct Phone</th><th>Cell Phone</th>
            <th>Supervisor</th><th>Location</th></tr>';
            // This var is just to count the lines returned.
            $index = 0;
            // Format all our results into our pretty table.
            foreach($data as $row)
            {
                if($searchRole != '%%' && $row['USR_MEMO_2'] == '')
                    continue;

                // Here we filter out numbers not matching our number search post-query.
                if($searchNum != '')
                    if (!((LikeMatch($searchNum,FormatNumber($row['WORK_PHONE'])))
                        || (LikeMatch($searchNum,FormatNumber($row['CELLULAR'])))
                        || (LikeMatch($searchNum,FormatNumber($row['OTHER_PHONE'])))))
                        continue;
                $index++;
                echo '<br/><br/>';
                echo '<tr><td>' .$row['USR_FIELD_11'] . '</td><td>' . $row['NAME_LAST']
                . '</td><td>';
                // if ($row['NAME_OTHER'] != null)
                //  echo $row['NAME_OTHER'];
                // else
                    echo $row['NAME_FIRST'];
                    echo '</td><td class="cell">'. $row['NAME_OTHER']. '</td><td class="cell">' . $row['USR_MEMO_2'] . '</td><td class="phone">' . FormatPhone($row['WORK_PHONE'])
                . '</td><td class="phone">' .   FormatPhone($row['OTHER_PHONE']) . '</td><td class="phone">' . FormatPhone($row['CELLULAR'])
                . '</td><td>' . $row['OTHER_CONTACT'] . '</td><td>' . $row['USR_FIELD_12'] . '</td></tr>';
            }

            echo '</table>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<b>No results found.</b>';
        }

        // disconnect
        $db = null;
    }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
    }
 }
function FormatNumber ($input)
{
    // Removes special characters from a phone number for comparison testing/searching
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9,]|,[0-9]*$/','',$input);
}
function FormatPhone ($input)
{
    //return preg_replace('~.*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{4}).*~', '($1) $2-$3', $input);
    // no area code:
    return preg_replace('~.*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{4}).*~', '$2-$3', $input);
}
function LikeMatch($input, $base)
{
    // Used for searching if a string is contained in another string.
    if(strpos($base, $input)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see any `echo` in this code.

Comment: I didn't post all of the code. The echo statements are further down in the  PHP code. As I said, it works fine if I just run the PHP file. If I load it in a DIV on my main HTML page, only the form in the PHP file loads and when I do a search I don't see the results. I want the results to display in the same DIV that the PHP loads into on my main HTML page.

Comment: Isn't because you have an `if` statement that may be returning false?

Comment: If you could create a [MRE] with the minimum amount of code required to produce the problem ,we can take a look at what is happening to be find where the problem is. For example you've included info that isn't related to the problem e.g. the `head` and all of the options in the `select` ( just a couple will do unless that is that of the problem too), however you haven't shown us the code with the `echo`, which is actually related to the problem :)

Comment: I edited the original with an example of my html file and the php file.